# How to load images with glide dynamically (Android)?

Tags: android

In my android app I pull data from http requests.

In my layout I want to show images dynamically with Glide library.

I get the image urls but I can not find a way to show them in my layout.

In my layout file I have:

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/social_media_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

  </LinearLayout>
```

Somehow I want to add imageviews(dynamically) in my LinearLayout.

For example: If I get 2 image urls from the request I need two imageviews in my linearlayout.

Note: I want to load images with Glide library.

Any idea would be helful.

Thanks.

Comment: get the LinearLayout view instance, then create your ImageViews and add the images you want, then use linearLayout.addView(image); to add the view

Comment: Very likely, you should used a ListView or RecyclerView instead of a LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a new XML file for `item_social_media.xml`

For example

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/social_media_icon" 
        />

        <!-- More customization as needed -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

And you can inflate that and add into the LinearLayout.

```
final Context context = MainActivity.this; // TODO: Get a context

// Inflate and update the view
View socialMediaItem = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_social_media);
ImageView icon = (ImageView) socialMediaItem.findViewById(R.id.social_media_icon);
// TODO: Glide ... into(icon);

// Add to the LinearLayout
linearLayout.addView(socialMediaItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should better use ListView or RecycleView . But if you insist on adding them into LinearLayout dynamically, then:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.social_media_layout);

// assuming that image_urls_list contains the images urls
for(int i=0;i<image_urls_list.size();i++)
{
    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);

    // set whatever width and height you want to give
    image.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100,100));

    // load image using Glide
     Glide.with(context).load(image_urls_list.get(i)).into(image);

    // Adds the view to the layout
    layout.addView(image);
}
```

You might want to add a HorizontalScrollView tag as a parent tag to your LinearLayout so that you can scroll horizontally.